# Python. How to make list from another list by mark?

Tags: python

I have list:

```
['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345']
```

Need to get:

```
['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4',['123','1234','12345']]
```

*If sorted by [0:3] symbols*

```
[['a','ab','abc'],'2','3','4',['1','123','1234','12345']]
```

*if sorted by [0:1] symbols*

list with another lists (strings with the same symbols only first symbol or any [:])
another example:

```
['some','son','abc','123','12345']
```

*If sorted by "123" - need:*

```
['some','son','abc',['123','12345']]
```

*If sorted by [0:1] - need:*

```
[['some','son'],'abc',['123','12345']]
```

and so on...

Sorry for my english and simple question.
Need help. Don't kill me at first question. Thank you.

Comment: what on earth are you talking about? You have to be clearer. What do you mean by "sorted by [0:3] symbols"?

Comment: It seems you want to group strings by their first `n` characters, for any `n`. What if your list is `['asdf', 'fdsa', 'asd']` with `n=3`?

Comment: There is no one way to sort your strings, because they all have different formats and requirements.

Comment: Sorry, i specify range such as the first three characters and because of their finding in the first list (in items, not in all), I need to create a second list with sublist with items with duplicated range.

Comment: I need to get [['asdf','asd'], 'fdsa'] if n=3. But i know only range (3 symbols). I don't know which symbols.

Comment: if i have ['asdf', 'fdsa', 'asd','123','1234','1','12345'] and n = 3 I need to get [['asdf','asd'],'fdsa','1',['123','1234','12345']]

Comment: @blackbird-: is order important for the rest of the sequence? You pulled `asd` forward there.

Comment: @blackbird-: shouldn't the numbers be first? numbers come before letters when you sort usually: `sorted(['a', '1'])` --> `['1', 'a']`

Comment: @blackbird- Place that last example in your question. That greatly helps

Comment: > is order important for the rest of the sequence? >> No. Sorry, I could express the idea is not entirely accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *group* items on their prefix, so use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(slice(n)))]
```

This returns a list of lists, consistently.

Note that this only groups consecutive values, it won't sort the input list for you. Adding sorting is as easy as re-using the key:

```
def sorted_group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    key = itemgetter(slice(n))
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(inputlist, key=key), key=key)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 3)
[['a'], ['ab'], ['abc'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['123', '1234', '12345']]
>>> group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 1)
[['a', 'ab', 'abc'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['123', '1234', '12345']]
>>> sorted_group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 3)
[['1'], ['123', '1234', '12345'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['a'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
>>> sorted_group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 1)
[['1', '123', '1234', '12345'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['a', 'ab', 'abc']]
```

If you *must* have lists only for groups longer than one elements use:

```
def group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    return [res[0] if len(res) == 1 else res for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(slice(n))) for res in (list(g),)]
```

or

```
def sorted_group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    key = itemgetter(slice(n))
    return [res[0] if len(res) == 1 else res for k, g in groupby(sorted(inputlist, key=key), key=key) for res in (list(g),)]
```

This gives:

```
>>> group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 3)
['a', 'ab', 'abc', '1', '2', '3', '4', ['123', '1234', '12345']]
>>> group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 1)
[['a', 'ab', 'abc'], '1', '2', '3', '4', ['123', '1234', '12345']]
>>> sorted_group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 3)
['1', ['123', '1234', '12345'], '2', '3', '4', 'a', 'ab', 'abc']
>>> sorted_group_by_start(['a','ab','abc','1','2','3','4','123','1234','12345'], 1)
[['1', '123', '1234', '12345'], '2', '3', '4', ['a', 'ab', 'abc']]
>>> sorted_group_by_start(['asdf', 'fdsa', 'asd','123','1234','1','12345'], 3)
['1', ['123', '1234', '12345'], ['asdf', 'asd'], 'fdsa']
```

You can turn either version into a generator to build the output lazily:

```
def group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    return (list(g) for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(slice(n))))
```

or

```
def group_by_start(inputlist, n):
    for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(slice(n))):
        res = list(g)
        yield res[0] if len(res) == 1 else res
```

then just loop over the output of the generator with `for` or cast to a list with `list()`.

Comment: In the demo for `group_by_start(..., 1)` isn't the list `['1']` a mistake. The element `"1"` would belong to the other group `['123', '1234', '12345']`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @EMS: Not for the unsorted version. But I had some C&P weirdness going on earlier. Let me re-generate.

Comment: @EMS: No, all groups are there entirely correctly. The *sorted* version has `'1'` put together with the `'123', '1234', '12345'` group, but unsorted they are not adjacent.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. This difference between `itertools.groupby` and `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` (which sorts implicitly, then groups) is the source of much consternation for me at times.

Comment: Can i do the same thing, but not to definite slice (slice(n)), but concrete finding symbols (target)? Or what is the simple way to do it?

I need to start grouping list by '123', then, when i get the next iteration of my loop, group by 'abcdef', then another symbols and so on.

After each iteration of loop i need to get the list grouped by finding word / symbol.

Comment: @blackbird-: you can use different keys to create groups; the `itemgetter(slice(n))` key is *just* a function, that given a string, returns the first `n` characters. You can give it a `lambda` too, or a whole function. It needs to take one argument (a value to sort or to group) and return the value to group or sort *by*.